# How to set url for twilio voice api?

Tags: python, flask, twilio

I'm new to flask. I used url_for function to locate twilio xml file for responding the call. I'm running my app in local host. While Executing this code it returns unable to find that xml file error.
The error number is 21205

my route is:

```
@app.route('/scall', methods=['POST'])
def scall():
    account_sid = '***************'
    auth_token = '***************'
    client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)
    phonenumber = request.form['phonenumber']
    call = client.calls.create(
                        url="url_for('templates', filename='res.xml')",
                        to='+91' + phonenumber,
                        from_='************'
                    )
```

Comment: Try to remove the quotation marks around the `url_for()` call.

Comment: What is your project structure? Where do you have `templates` directory? Do you have `res.xml` file there? How do you create `Flask` instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Your problem is that Twilio is trying to find that XML file in a place it doesn't have access to.

When you pass the `url` parameter, you're simply telling Twilio what to do when a call is answered. So Twilio then makes an HTTP request to that XML file which will hopefully have TwiML it understands.

What you need to do instead is give it a URL that is accessible publically. There are a few options for how to do this:

1. Host the XML somewhere accessible (S3, Dropbox, your webserver, etc)
2. Create a [TwiML Bin](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/230878368-How-to-use-templates-with-TwiML-Bins) inside the Twilio console and point directly to it.
3. Use a tool like [ngrok](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2013/10/test-your-webhooks-locally-with-ngrok.html) to expose your localhost and point to that URL from within your code.

Hope this helps you out.